# Unable to connect to cosmos db emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Document Db version 2.6 and I am unable to connect to Cosmos Db emulator. I am trying to connect to https://localhost:8081. I am getting below error after it executes this line:

```
// Open the connection
documentClient.OpenAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

> WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'localhost-eastus2euap'

I am not sure how it's connecting to this url "localhost-eastus2euap" when I am trying to connect to localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding regions to the ConnectionPolicy PreferredLocations, is that correct?

When working with the emulator, adding regions is not supported, there are no regions as it is running in an isolated environment.

If this is code that hits the emulator or a live account, some configuration might be added to know when to add the regions and when not to.